# I want to add a picture to the right of the heading while keeping the heading in the center of the page

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want the text to stay centered in the middle of the page and add a picture about a 100px to the right of the text.

```
<p style=background-color:#FFFFFF;
         font-size:600%;
         text-align:center;
         color:red;>
    Great Sheds
    <img style=margin:100px src="transomshutter.jpg" height="84" width="168">
</p>
```

This is the current section of code. It moves the text over to the left and then the picture is not in line with the text.  It is above and to the right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using absolute positioning on the img. This will position the image 100px from the right edge of the paragraph. Adjust the "right" value to the amount you want. You should use position:relative on the paragraph tag ("p") if you want to to this.

```
<img style="position: absolute;right: 100px;" src="transomshutter.jpg" height="84" width="168">
```

Answer (score 1):

If you always know the width of the image, you can use it to offset a negative right direction with absolute positioning, like so:

```
p {
  position: relative;
}
p img {
  position: absolute;
  right: -268px;
}
```

Alternatively, if you're not worried about older browsers, you can use calc() to determine the left side:

```
p img {
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(100% + 100px);
}
```

EDIT: correction, I misread the left and right of your question. I have adjusted my answer for that.